# Params not present error in the pictures model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `picture` model which uses `carrierwave` to upload files. The `picture` model is a polymorphic relationship with `user` model and `scoreboard` model.  All the relevant code is given below.

**The pictureable controller**

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController        
  before_filter :load_pictureable
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @picture = @pictureable.build_picture(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
        flash[:success] = "Uploaded Successfully"
        redirect_to @pictureable
    else
        redirect_to @pictureable
        flash[:danger] = "An error occured, please try again!"
    end
  end

  def update
    @picture = @pictureable.picture
    if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
       redirect_to @pictureable
       flash[:success] = "Picture updated successfully"
     else
       redirect_to @pictureable
       flash[:danger] = "An error occured, please try again!"
     end
  end

  def destroy
    @pictureable.picture.delete
    redirect_to @pictureable
    flash[:success] = "Picture removed successfully"
  end

private

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:picture)
  end

  def load_pictureable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
    @pictureable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end
end
```

I use HTML5 e-reader Javascript on the front end to read the image in a modal.  The file shows up in the modal just fine. The Javascript code is given below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var preview = $(".upload-preview img");

    $(".hidden").change(function(event){
       var input = $(event.currentTarget);
       var file = input[0].files[0];
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function(e){
           $('#image')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(307)
                    .height(317);
           image_base64 = e.target.result;
           preview.attr("src", image_base64);
       };
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
});
```

The `create` action works perfectly.  However, when I try to update an existing picture it **sometimes** gives me the following error: `param is missing or the value is empty: picture.`  The error only occurs sometimes.  I am not exactly sure what's happening.  I understand that the error is telling me that `picture` param isn't present.

LOG file for an UNSUCCESSFUL patch request.

```
Started PATCH "/scoreboards/7/pictures/24" for 70.26.106.141 at 2016-05-17 16:27:32 +0000
Processing by PicturesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WoA40xzlc8CH6/gcf6Jd/nqlj/9iOoykcn4H9zAgTkuwi6vAttZEPECYs+OfHZvC3le3nY/sZ/IZSwOL0FhnIQ==", "scoreboard_id"=>"7", "id"=>"24"}
  [1m[36mScoreboard Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "scoreboards".* FROM "scoreboards" WHERE "scoreboards"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "scoreboards"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 7]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mPicture Load (14.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."pictureable_id" = $1 AND "pictures"."pictureable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1[0m  [["pictureable_id", 7], ["pictureable_type", "Scoreboard"]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 24ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: picture):
  app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:40:in `picture_params'
  app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:20:in `update'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (110.5ms)
```

LOG file for a successful POST request

```
Started POST "/scoreboards/7/pictures" for 70.26.106.141 at 2016-05-17 16:30:00 +0000
Processing by PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jNhAeqUJNZGKEGdDCWSGzGRBSwyXkQIj9iZgMMklqBpm09NpDzoCbU1jLLzp20DwwLNzbnpH6XWdE2RMKV2BcA==", "picture"=>{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006c6b7d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160517-27824-1d2x6l4.jpeg>, @original_filename="Home_pic.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[picture]\"; filename=\"Home_pic.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "scoreboard_id"=>"7"}
  [1m[35mScoreboard Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  "scoreboards".* FROM "scoreboards" WHERE "scoreboards"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "scoreboards"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35mPicture Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."pictureable_id" = $1 AND "pictures"."pictureable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["pictureable_id", 7], ["pictureable_type", "Scoreboard"]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "pictures" ("picture", "pictureable_id", "pictureable_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["picture", "Home_pic.jpeg"], ["pictureable_id", 7], ["pictureable_type", "Scoreboard"], ["created_at", "2016-05-17 16:30:03.046590"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-17 16:30:03.046590"]]
  [1m[36m (29.2ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to https://scorecliq-kpauls.c9users.io/scoreboards/7
Completed 302 Found in 2253ms (ActiveRecord: 31.2ms)
```

The view file is handled in the modal.  The code is given below.  The `editphoto` modal and `upload photo` modal are the same thing.  **Below is the EDITPHOTO modal/UPLOAD PHOTO.**

```
<div>
  <%= form_for([@pictureable, @picture], html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png', id: "files", class: "hidden" %>

     <div class="modal fade" id="picmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="picmodal" aria-hidden="true"> 
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center">Selected Image</div>
             <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="upload-preview" style="text-align: center">
               <img id="image" /></img>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <%= f.submit "upload photo", class: "hidden", id: "editphotobutton" %>
                <button class="btn-s btn-full", for: "editphotobutton">Save Changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The View code where I click on options to change the picture

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 score-prof-pic">
         <% if @picture.picture.url.present? %>
            <div class="dropdown">
               <%= link_to "#", class: "prof-dropdown" , data: {:toggle => "dropdown"}, role: "button", aria: {:expanded => "false"} do %>
                   <%= image_tag @picture.picture.url, class: "prof-default img-thumbnail" %>
               <% end %>
               <% if manager_or_owner?(@scoreboard, current_user) %>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li><%= link_to "Upload","#", id: "score-prof-edit" %> </li>
                     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                     <li> <%= link_to "Remove", [@pictureable, @picture], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete your picture!"} %></li>
                     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                     <li><%= link_to "Cancel", "#" %></li>
                  </ul>
               <% end %>
            </div>
         <% else %>
            <div class="dropdown">
               <%= link_to "#", class: "prof-dropdown" , data: {:toggle => "dropdown"}, role: "button", aria: {:expanded => "false"} do %>
                   <%= image_tag "blank-prof.jpg", class: "prof-default img-thumbnail " %>
               <% end %>
               <% if manager_or_owner?(@scoreboard, current_user) %>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><%= link_to "Upload","#", id: "score-prof-upload" %> </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Cancel", "#" %></li>
               </ul>
               <% end %>
            </div>
         <% end %>
     </div>
```

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, I will post the logs file for update and create in the original question.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, The question is updated with the log files.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, I posted the view code. That is pretty much all I used to handle the pictures. The JS on the front end and the rails at the backend.

Comment: Are you referring to this? `def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:picture)
end`

Comment: Could it be that your issue occues when the update is done with no new picture uploaded?  The picture_params require a picture to be uploaded when you update.

Comment: If there is no picture uploaded, the form makes a call to the create method in the controller instead. The puzzling thing is that the update method only works successfully sometimes. When it doesn't work, the log file gives a `Completed bad request 400`. Upon some research, other people have noticed this problem with a jquery.post but I cannot make sense of it. lol i'm losing hair.

Comment: I didn't see a jQuery POST (Ajax?) in your Javascript.  Only the renderer for the preview.  Is there more Javascript code?  Or is that handled by a component that I've overlooked?

Comment: Yea, I mistook the renderer for a POST. That's all the code.

Comment: You said "If there is no picture uploaded, the form makes a call to the create method in the controller instead", but I don't see any code that does that.  How does that happen?  The logs for the unsuccessful update show that there's no picture data sent from the form to the action.  This was why I said that your update action requires you to upload a new picture to work.  Can you clarify?

Comment: My apologies. I've made another update of the view interface code I use to change the image. Clicking on either of the upload buttons renders the upload modal form. The create and upload methods both use the same form. If an image is not present, the form makes a call to the create method. If an image is present the form routes to the update method. Is it ok that I use the same form for create and update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails strong parameters for the controller is currently requiring that a new picture be uploaded when the user updates the Picture model.  This means that if the user submits the form without having uploaded a new image, even if they had previously uploaded an image successfully, the strong parameters will fail the action.

To fix this, change the `picture_params` method to this:

```
def picture_params
  params.permit(:picture)
end
```

This will allow `update` to work, even if the user has not chosen a new file.  Ideally, the UI would disable the `Save` or `Submit` button until the user has chosen a file to upload, in order to ensure a good user experience.

To verify that the user has uploaded a file at least one time, add a validation to the Picture model to validate that a picture exists for the user.  Without knowing the specific details of your field names, you could validate like this (assuming that `:image` :

```
def Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :has_picture

private

  def has_picture
    errors.add(:picture, "can't be missing") if !picture.url.present?
  end
end
```

This approach will give you validation at save time, rather than when the action is called.  This should not only make the action more robust, but ensure that the model is always valid.

Comment: While my wording for this question was wrong, you helped me reach the conclusion that the upload form sometimes doesn't accept files.I tried making it visible and it answered a lot. While this solution works, it is not what I was looking for. I need to fix the form itself. However my question may be misleading, therefore I will ask a clearer one.

Comment: Hey, glad to have helped in some way.  Good luck!